# Debug ipad application on real device in VMWare

Tags: iphone, ipad

Right now i develop ipad application in vmware macos X image. Is it possible to deploy application on real device and debug it in vmware image?

Comment: I should point out that running a Mac OS X software image in VMWare is a violation of Apple's license.

Comment: You posted in the wrong forum, stackoverflow is strictly for technical issues. I suggest you use Google to find forums discussing Apple's license policy if you really need to help Apple with legal matters.

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt matter if you use vmware or a real mac, as long as the xcode organizer recognizes the device when you attach it to an usb port.

To deploy an application on a real device you need developer certificates from apple. (You need to pay the $99 to them to be a registered iphone developer to get them). You can then register your device at developer.apple.com and you can run applications on it which you have signed with your certificate.

If the device is jailbroken it can be done without proper certificates, but I have never done that.

Comment: I have developer certificate. I need to know xcode under vmware will recognize connected ipad for debug purposes?

Comment: I just tried this with certificates I have confirmed are working on my Mac, and the iOS device is not recognized. I read some claims it is possible though. Still researching...

Comment: by the way, jailbreaking your device wont help you to debug on it. Only to install apps without Apples certificates.